# c++ Windows 10 Get an Ip for a connected client

Tags: c++, server, ip-address, winsock2

I have set up a working WinSock2 Socket were a client can connect, how can I get the IP address of a connected client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client's IP address is reported by [`accept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) when the client is first accepted.  It can also be queried from the client `SOCKET` at any time using [`getpeername()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getpeername).  Both functions fill in a `sockaddr_...` struct that you must allocate and pass in, based on the address type assigned when you created the server socket using `socket()`:

- If `AF_INET`, provide a `sockaddr_in` struct:

```cpp
sockaddr_in clientAddr;
int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
SOCKET client = accept(server, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize);
if (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // use client_addr.sin_addr as needed...
    ...
    clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if (getpeername(client, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize) == 0)
    {
        // use client_addr.sin_addr as needed...
    }
    ...
    closesocket(client);
}
```

- If `AF_INET6` with `IPV6_V6ONLY` enabled, provide a `sockaddr_in6` struct:

```cpp
sockaddr_in6 clientAddr;
int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
SOCKET client = accept(server, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize);
if (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // use client_addr.sin6_addr as needed...
    ...
    clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if (getpeername(client, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize) == 0)
    {
        // use client_addr.sin6_addr as needed...
    }
    ...
    closesocket(client);
}
```

- If `AF_INET6` with `IPV6_V6ONLY` disabled, provide a `sockaddr_storage` struct, and then look at its `ss_family` field to know whether to cast the `sockaddr_storage` data to `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`:

```cpp
sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
sockaddr_in *clientAddr4;
sockaddr_in6 *clientAddr6;
int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
SOCKET client = accept(server, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize);
if (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    switch (client_addr.ss_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
            clientAddr4 = use reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(&client_addr);
            // use clientAddr4->sin_addr as needed...
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            clientAddr6 = use reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(&client_addr);
            // use clientAddr6->sin6_addr as needed...
            break;
    }
    ...
    clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if (getpeername(client, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientAddrSize) == 0)
    {
        switch (client_addr.ss_family)
        {
            case AF_INET:
                clientAddr4 = use reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(&client_addr);
                // use clientAddr4->sin_addr as needed...
                break;
            case AF_INET6:
                clientAddr6 = use reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(&client_addr);
                // use clientAddr6->sin6_addr as needed...
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
    closesocket(client);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a sockaddr_in from the socket?

Comment: @ColinSutter no, you have to pre-allocate it and pass it in to the socket to be filled in. The only function that will allocate a `sockaddr_...` for you is `getaddrinfo()`, but that is for hostname lookups, not socket queries.